# Can description be used as search parameter in Google App Script's DriveApp.searchFiles()

Tags: google-apps-script

As the title of the question states, is it possible to add description as a parameter in the DriveApp.searchFiles(string param)

I've searched through the documentation and no mention of it is made. It just seems wierd that you would no be able to search based on this. Google documentation is also poor at the best of times, I have an alternative solution, I would be interested in using the below method though.

```
var folderID = "123456789";
var description = "Processed";

DriveApp.searchFiles( folderID + "in Parents" + "and Description is " + description);
```

### **Documentation:**

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchfilesparams

Comment: Here's the extensive list of all of the [available search query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms) for `DriveApp.searchFiles()`, looks like you can make use of the `fullText` term for your purpose.

Comment: Oh snap I somehow missed that. So I could do something like DriveApp.searchfiles("full text contains " + description") going to test it now. (Thanks for the help.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Answer:

*As a direct answer to your question, **no, it is not possible to add `description` as a parameter in the `DriveApp.searchFiles()` method.***

#### Workaround:

You can workaround this using the `fullText` query term, however be aware that this will also return any files that contain the term in their content, ineditable text or title.

```js
var folderID = '<folder-id>';
var description = "Processed";

var files = DriveApp.searchFiles(
 "'" + folderID +"'" + " in Parents" + " and fullText contains " + "'" + description + "'"
);
```

You can use the `title` parameter to filter out files which contain it in the title, but the others are not directly searchable.

#### References:

- [Class `DriveApp`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app)

  - [`searchFiles(params)` method of DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#searchFiles(String))
- [Search query Terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms)

  - [File query terms](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/ref-search-terms#file_properties)

Comment: Thanks Rafa, I fixed up the query string.

Comment: No worries - I kept the `description` variable as the string `'Processed'` is defined 2 lines before but thanks for pointing that out :)